# JavaScript to write the values of textbox to a csv file and save to server

Tags: javascript

I want to use JavaScript to

1. Write the values of textbox to a csv file
2. Save the csv file with the value of first textbox (nameField)
3. Save the csv file to a path (data folder) on the server
4. And download at the same time to client system...

```html
Name: <input type="text" id="nameField">
Position: <input type="text" id="positionField">
<input type="Submit" Value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

To give the user a prompt to download a CSV file, you can use the download attribute of the `<a>` tag. As for saving it on the server, you will either need to submit a form or send an AJAX request to your server.

```
<textarea>
John,Doe,1
Jane,Doe,2
</textarea>
<br/>
<button>Download as CSV</button>
<script>
function promptDownload(content, fileName) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(content);
  a.download = fileName;
  a.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a);
}
var btn = document.querySelector("button"),
txtArea = document.querySelector("textarea");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  promptDownload(txtArea.value, "Test.csv");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @hev1. This script is working...but I still want to save the csv file on the server at thesame time.....please any other way to do that?

Save the csv file with the value of first textbox (nameField)
Save the csv file to a path (data folder) on the server